# Low frame time for CPU and GPU, low frame rate?

Tags: ios, xcode, frame, rate

I am having some trouble grasping why my app performance is at 24fps as opposed to the usual 30fps.

The frame time for both CPU and GPU varies between 6-18 ms, and the GPU utilization never surpasses 55%. Doesn't this mean that the frame rate should be higher?

When I use 'Analyze Performance', Xcode tells me:
Your performance is not limited by the OpenGL ES commands issued. Use the Instruments tool to investigate where your application is bottlenecked.

I am a beginner at this, so can someone explain to me how the frame time can be so low, yet the frame rate so high? (The device is not the issue)

**Edit 4/2/2013**

New development: 
This frame rate drop only occurs when I run the app from Xcode (I know this because when the app performance is poor, the sound is not in sync and accelerometer sensitivity is lowered). When I stop running from Xcode and run the app directly from my iPod, the frame rate is perfect. Now I am wondering if there really are performance issues with my app. Is there any way that Xcode could be impeding on the app's performance by running tests or monitoring the device?

Answer (score 0):

You should set frame rate to your avCaptureConnection.And then it shoud be ok.